# Confidence intervals converging to credible intervals when Bootstraping?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, bootstrap, credible-interval

As [explained already by Rasmus](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2015/04/the-non-parametric-bootstrap-as-a-bayesian-model/), the Bayesian Bootstrap and the non-parametric Bootstrap "converge" when n is sufficiently large.

But if taking the percentile interval in the Bayesian Bootstrapped distribution will approximate a credible interval (or did I misunderstand something?) and the percentile interval in a Non-Parametric Bootstrapped distribution will approximate a confidence interval.

Would that imply that when using Bootstrapping (either Bayesian or non-parametric) and when n is sufficiently large (Here I do not mean asymptotically but rather a reasonable number) the confidence interval will be approximately the same as the credible interval?